# jQuery autocomplete с разными источниками

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Можно ли средствами стандартного autocomplete реализовать «подтягивание» данных из двух разных источников по условию (regex, numeric) — то есть, при совпадении вводимой строки с условием регулярного выражения или проверки на «число»: поиск по id, в противном случае, поиск по совпадению имени? Если бы это было на собственном сервере, то не составило бы труда осуществлять переадресацию по типу запроса, но речь идет о стороннем api. В принципе, можно было бы осуществлять запрос на свой же сервер и оттуда делать запрос на нужный api, но вариант не лучший.

Comment: Если вас интересует вопрос "можно ли?" - ответ: Да можно. Если у вас есть конкретный вопрос(а не задача, аки сделайте код за меня) - вы можете дополнить свой вопрос примерами кода, и вашими попытками это реализовать, а мы уже попробуем вам подсказать.

Comment: Ну наверное, я не из праздного любопытства, интересуюсь можно ли... Я прекрасно знаю, как составить запрос, но autocomplete принимает объект с одним полем url и изменять его на лету не представляется возможным

Comment: Почему 90% вопрошающих тут никогда не трудятся даже глянуть в документацию? Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кусок кода из официальной документации по JQuery UI:

```
 .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( "search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        },
```

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Кто простите вам запрещает захреначить `"search.php"` в переменную и менять ее динамически?)

90% поведения jQuery UI настраивается функциями(как они правильно называются не знаю, но почти вместо любого параметра можно дать инлайн функцию).